# Error when saving a composed midi file with midiutils

Tags: python, midi

I have an array of [note, octave, time distance from past note] loaded. The midi file doesn't want to save, and causes an error. The sequence is ai generated, and time distance doesn't follow any pattern. Is this the problem?

Traceback:
Error:Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\MusicGen\outputs\get_midi.py", line 44, in 
midi_file.writeFile(output_file)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\midiutil\MidiFile.py", line 1637, in writeFile
self.close()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\midiutil\MidiFile.py", line 1688, in close
self.tracks[i].closeTrack()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\midiutil\MidiFile.py", line 826, in closeTrack
self.processEventList()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\midiutil\MidiFile.py", line 789, in processEventList
self.deInterleaveNotes()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\midiutil\MidiFile.py", line 885, in deInterleaveNotes
if len(stack[noteeventkey]) > 1:
KeyError: '50'
exception:  '50' None

```
import pickle
from midiutil import MIDIFile

out = pickle.load(open("generated_sequence", "rb"))

ticks_per_quarter_note = 220  
track_number = 0
channel_number = 0
tempo = 150

notes_array = [[i[0]%12, i[0]//12, i[1]] for i in out]

# Create a MIDIFile object
midi_file = MIDIFile(numTracks=1)
midi_file.addTrackName(track_number, 0, "Track 0")
midi_file.addTempo(track_number, 0, tempo)

# Loop through the notes and add them to the MIDI file
time = 0
for note in notes_array:
    
    # Calculate the note's pitch
    pitch = note[0] + (note[1] * 12)
    
    # Convert the note's duration from milliseconds to ticks
    duration = int(note[2] / (1000 / (tempo / 60 * ticks_per_quarter_note)))

    # Calculate the note's position in time
    time += duration
    # Add the note to the MIDI file
    midi_file.addNote(
        track_number,
        channel_number,
        pitch,
        time,
        duration,
        100  # you can adjust the velocity (volume) here
    )

# Save the MIDI file
with open("my_midi_file.mid", "wb") as output_file:
    midi_file.writeFile(output_file)
```

Comment: The error could be due to various reasons, such as invalid arguments passed to the MIDI file creation or note addition functions, or a problem with the MIDI library installation.

Comment: "The midi file doesn't want to save" This tells us nearly nothing about what actually happened.  Please edit the question and add the **whole** error traceback message.